# What is the type of unmodifiable list in java

Tags: java, collections

Unmodifiable list in java can be created as:

```
List<String> unModifiableStringList = Collections.unmodifiableList(myActualModifiableList);
```

This is fine, but what is the actual runtime type of the list returned by the above function? How can we access that class? Is it even possible?

**UPDATE:** Actually I need to know at compile time that an unmodifiable list is being modified, Since I have to deal with a lot of lists, some of which are modifiable and others are not. So it is very cumbersome to keep track?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Actually I need to know at compile time that an unmodifiable list is being modified.

That is not possible.

Or at least, it is not possible without creating a completely different collections interface / class hierarchy.  And that's a bad idea because nothing designed to use regular collections would work with it.

I suppose it would be possible to write a static code analyser that could detect this kind of thing ... in *some* cases ... but that's not strictly "compile time".  Besides, I'm not aware of any existing static code analyser that does this "out of the box".

---

> I wonder if there was a reason why they did it like this.

Well none of the ways you *might* do this really work.

Alternative #1:

```
 public interface UnmodifiableList<T> {
     public T get(int pos);
     ....
 }

 public interface List<T> extends UnmodifiableList<T> {
     public void add(T elem);
     ....
 }
```

While static typing can prevent us from using an unmodifiable list where a modifiable one is required, the reverse is not true.  Every List is also an UnmodifiableList ... and that doesn't really make sense.

Alternative 2:

```
 public interface List <T> {
     public T get(int pos);
     public void add(T elem);
     ....
 }

 public interface UnmodifiableList<T> {
     // A marker interface
 }
```

Now static typing can prevent us from using an modifiable list where an umodifiable one is required, but not the reverse.  (That suits your requirement ...)  Furthermore, a class that implements `UnmodifiableList` still inherits the `add` operation, and there's nothing to stop an application from trying to call it.

In short, static type systems cannot adequately handle this kind of restriction.

Comment: As a general rule, you should code to interfaces rather than actual runtime classes.  `Collections.unmodifiableList` is designed, in fact, to _force_ you to code to the interface.

Comment: @LouisWasserman - I don't think that's relevant to the OP's followup questions; i.e. the ones I'm answering.

Comment: Eh?  I was trying to suggest another "reason why they did it like this."

Comment: @LouisWasserman - I know you were.  But the "it" you are referring to is not the "it" that the OP is asking about in his follow-up question / comment.

Comment: The reason the type system "can't handle it" is that you think that modifiable is the default. Consider if you had List -> ArrayList -> ModifiableArrayList for example. The Collections API would be very different, but you could do it. It's just a question of perspective.

Comment: @HaakonLøtveit - Actually, that approach doesn't work.  It is effectively my alternative #1.  The problem is that a modifiable list as a subtype of an unmodifiable list breaks the LSP!

Comment: @StephenC I see the argument, but the base class would not be unmodifiable list, it would just be a list. Lists would not have mutator methods, and you'd get used to it. There's a UX saying that I never found the source for that goes something like "Intuitive just means what your past experience have taught you". Which is pretty true. Learning BASH was weird for me who grew up with DOS, but not too strange. - instead of /, and no cd.. shortcut, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `unModifiableStringList.getClass().getName()`?

To me it gives

```
java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList
```

which, as seen from the source code, is a package-access static inner class of `Collections`.

Answer (score 3):

It is

```
static class UnmodifiableList<E> extends UnmodifiableCollection<E>
                      implements List<E>

static class UnmodifiableRandomAccessList<E> extends UnmodifiableList<E>
                                      implements RandomAccess

static class UnmodifiableCollection<E> implements Collection<E>, Serializable
```

It is inner class of `Collections`, since `Collections` is non-instantiable and it is inner class with package visibility, you **can not** access the class, and it is the implementation hiding in OOP.

Comment: How can I check in my code whether a list is unmodifiable or not?

Comment: @djaqeel I think you only can check at runtime, but not compile time. And it is not recommend to check at runtime too.

Comment: @user517491 Here's a way to check if it is unmodifiable or not: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77971105/501113

Answer (score 2):

See: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29

It's an inner class in `Collections`:

```
static class UnmodifiableList<E> extends UnmodifiableCollection<E>
                                 implements List<E>
```

Answer (score 0):

Debug shows that the runtime type is `Collections.UnmodifiableRandomAccessList`, so it's internal class. Code analysis also shows that it might be `Collections.UnmodifiableList`.

You shouldn't try to access this class, it's meant to be immutable. Try to use common interface instead, in this case = `Collection`.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement clearly says its still reference of List but it suppress modification of the list.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)

If you share unmodifiable list reference you make sure that nobody changes it and allow read only operations.