# Creating an ImmutableList from an Iterable

Tags: java, java-8, guava

I need to fetch an object from each element in an `Iterable` and add it into a `List`.

I am able to do this using the code below. However, are there any ways of creating a Guava `ImmutableList` without instantiating a `List` explicitly?

```
List<Data> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myIterable.forEach(val ->
  myList.add(val.getMetaData())
);
```

Comment: You can use Collections.unmodifiable( List ) but this won't work well if Data isn't also immutable.

Comment: Are you trying to create a Guava `ImmutableList`, or just a list that happens to be immutable?

Comment: I am trying to create a Guava `ImmutableList`

Comment: @markspace I am trying to get `metaData` from `Data` and adding it to a List.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the type of unmodifiable list in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480173/what-is-the-type-of-unmodifiable-list-in-java)

Comment: No @akop. I am trying to fetch metadata from Data and trying to add it to a ImmutableList in this instance. The link seems to refer to converting Interable<Data> to List<Data> if I am not wrong.

Comment: @PunterVicky: Maybe edit your question and add that you're looking for a way to create a Guava `ImmutableList`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To apply a function to each element and turn it into an `ImmutableList`, today's best practice would be

```
Streams.stream(myIterable).map(Value::getMetaData)
  .collect(ImmutableList.toImmutableList());
```

Comment: You do not need Guava's `ImmutableList` class to do this. The standard `Collectors` class has `toUnmodifiableList`.

Comment: While that's true, the OP specifically requested an `ImmutableList`.

Comment: I see that now, not sure if the question was edited since I first read it or if I just missed that detail. Either way my comment may help someone down the road, so I will leave it.

Answer (score 1):

> are there any ways of creating an ImmutableList with instantiating the List explicitly?

### Solution using standard JDK features

You can use [`StreamSupport.stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/StreamSupport.html#stream(java.util.Spliterator,boolean)) to generate a stream out of your `Iterable` and then apply `map()` to transform to extract `Data` objects from stream elements and `toList()` to obtain an *immutable list* as the result:

```
List<Data> result = StreamSupport.stream(
        myIterable.spliterator(), // spliterator
        false                     // denotes whether the stream should be parallel or not
    )
    .map(MyClass::getMetaData)
    .toList();   // for Java 8 .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList())
```

[*A simple Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/tJf)

### JDK Stream API & Guava ImmutableList

The code might look like that:

```
List<Data> result = StreamSupport.stream(
        myIterable.spliterator(),
        false
    )                                               // Stream<MyClass>
    .map(MyClass::getMetaData)                      // Stream<Data>
    .collect(
        ImmutableList::<Data>builder,               // accumulation type - ImmutableList.Builder<Data>
        ImmutableList.Builder::add,                 // adding stream element into a builder
        (left, right) -> left.addAll(right.build()) // merging builders while executing in parallel
    )
    .build();   // building an ImmutableList
```

*###### To future readers:*

  <sub>The last code snippet which makes use of `ImmutableList.Builder` provided for rather educational purposes. If you are not particularly interested in `ImmutableList` from Guava library (for instance, you're not using this library in your project) then have a look at the solution at the **very beginning** of the answer. If you **do** want Guava's `ImmutableList` for some reason, then the better option would be to use the approach provided in the [*answer by Louis Wasserman*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73241591/17949945)</sub>

Comment: Thank you. In my case I am trying to add val.getMetaData() into the List object. Would this approach be able to help with that?

Comment: @PunterVicky Ok, now I see that meant `ImmutableList` from Guava library. At least I've shown an option that JDK offers.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander Invanchenko!