# How to return an unmodifiable Map in Java?

Tags: java, immutability

java.util.Collections has the unmodifiableMap method, which creates a view of the map, making it impossible to alter the map.

But why isn't there an ImmutableMap type? As the unmodifiableMap return is declared to be a simple Map, one could write this code:

```
class SomeClass {
    private Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
    public Map<String, Integer> getData () {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(data);
    }
}
```

elsewhere:

```
Map<String, Object> data = someClass.getData();
// no compiler warning here, but an UnsupportedOperationException at runtime
data.put("count", 17);
```

What is the best way to deal with this?

Why is such a type not in java.util? My expectation was to have such a type, making it clear that the value, returned from the getData method is not mutable. As there would be no put or any other method which will alter the value the code above would not compile.

Do I miss something here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test if a List<? extends Object> is an UnmodifableList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364856/how-to-test-if-a-list-extends-object-is-an-unmodifablelist)

Comment: There's the `ImmutableMap` interface in [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava); but this makes you dependent on a third-party library

Comment: Although the duplicate talks about `List.of()`, the answers apply for all Java collection types from the standard API.

Comment: @experiment unit: no. I want to let the user of the getData method know that he cannot modify the data.

Comment: @knittl: thanks, This might be the best option. Although: I don't like the idea of copying possibly large collections.

Comment: Then why not create your own implementation/wrapper of an ImmutableMap? Only provide a way to read values but not modify the data

Comment: About the "Why" question: Because at the time the Java collections API was invented (end of the 1990's), the developers of the JDK did not design it with immutability in mind. And now it cannot be changed without massively breaking backward compatibility.

Comment: I remember reading a detailed explanation of this by a Java architect.  Having a parallel class hierarchy (Map/ImmutableMap, Set/IImmutableSet, List/ImmutableList, etc.) is very messy.  It’s simply not worth the trouble.

Comment: [*Google Guava*](https://github.com/google/guava) and [*Eclipse Collections*](https://eclipse.dev/collections/) both provide types for immutable maps. Either gives you the type-safety protection you seek.