# Android: Incrementing an integer causes an allocation

Tags: java, android

The following line appears in the allocations pane of eclipse:

```
Alloc Order       Allocation Size           Allocated Class
509               12                        java.lang.Integer
```

It references this line of java code:

```
MyInteger++;
```

I changed it around a little bit, but it still causes an allocation.

```
MyInteger=MyInteger+1;
MyInteger=MyInteger+MyIntegerIncrementor;
```

Why do these lines of code cause an allocation?

Comment: What type of MyInteger? It should be int instead of Integer

Comment: for the purposes of this question it is Integer, whether using int or Integer is better depends on the context of your problem. In general you are right and int should be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `Integer` is [immutable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html), each time you increment it a new object is created, hence the allocation.

Comment: Is there any easy way to tell whether an Object is immutable?

Comment: @tjb Google/Documentation. This article lists immutable Objects http://www.javaranch.com/journal/2003/04/immutable.htm for instance.

Comment: @tbj You might be interested in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203475/how-do-i-identify-immutable-objects-in-java